# data in CSV from beautiful soup shows b or \n in front of everything

Tags: python, csv, beautifulsoup

I just started messing around with python and beautiful soup having an issue when I export to a CSV the rows in the CSV file show "b" or "\n" not sure what needs to be fixed.

I apologize if the code is sloppy I am still very new to all of this

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import requests
import csv

source = requests.get ('https://www.shopdisney.com/uniquely-disney/parks-inspired/walt-disney-world-50th-collection/').text
soup = BeautifulSoup(source, 'html.parser')

file = open ('Disney50th.csv', 'w')
writer = csv.writer(file)

#write header rows
writer.writerow(['Item Name', 'Item Price', 'Item Link'])

products = soup.find_all('div', class_="product__tile")

for item_info in products:
    
    price = item_info.find('span', class_='value')
    name = item_info.find('a', class_= "product__tile_link")
    link = item_info.find('a', class_= "product__tile_link")

    p = price.attrs['content']
    n = name.get_text('title')
    l = link.attrs['href']

    print ("Item Name =", n, '\n' "Item Link =", l, '\n' "Item Price =",p)

    writer.writerow([n.encode('utf-8'), p.encode('utf-8'), l.encode('utf-8')])

file.close
```

The CSV shows as follows:

[image: Image of CSV in editor]

Thank you for any help in advance.

Comment: If you feel an answer solved the problem, please mark it as 'accepted' by clicking the green check mark. This helps keep the focus questions that still don't have answers. Otherwise please let us know what issues you still face, if they are within the scope of this question.

Answer (score 0):

The `b` in front of stuff is because of the `.encode('utf-8')` when you do

```py
writer.writerow([n.encode('utf-8'), p.encode('utf-8'), l.encode('utf-8')])
```

This turns those values from [`str`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#text-sequence-type-str) objects into [`bytes`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#bytes-objects). You should simply be able to remove them and use the following instead:

```py
writer.writerow([n, p, l])
```

As for the spaces and `\n`, that's because the strings you're adding has those characters in them. You can remove them with [`str.strip`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#str.strip) like so:

```py
writer.writerow([n.strip(), p.strip(), l.strip()])
```

Or equivalently:

```py
writer.writerow([x.strip() for x in (n, p, l)])
```